# What is the difference between 感触 and 触感

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

From my limited research both mean "tactile sensation". 触感 strictly means "tactile sensation" while 感触 can have a broader meaning closer to 感覚 and 印象. Also according to Anime, Jdrama and Netflix frequency lists, 感触 is far more common than 触感.

That being said, what is the main difference between these two words? Why would someone pick one over the other when it comes to using "tactile sensation" and what some example usages of 感触 apart from "touch, texture"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your first paragraph more or less states the difference: (1) 感触 is more common and (2) 感触 can be used in a more abstract sense as in "I have the feeling that....". Another point may be that 感触 usually implies an animate "feeler".

- 面接の感触は良かった (literally) The feeling of the interview was good.
- 面接がうまくいったという感触がある I have the feeling that the interview went well.

Both are examples of "abstract" usage and basically say the same thing. 触感 cannot be used here.

To me, 触感 is used for describing the feeling of (e.g. surface of) something.

- この生地はごわごわした触感だ/この生地の触感はごわごわしている　This cloth has rough texture.

In this sense, texture/touch may be closer to 触感. Here 感触 may be less common but acceptable.

Comment: Is that to say that you wouldn't used 感触 to talk about a tactile feeling/texture? I always thought 感触 was easier to use because it doesn't sound similar to 食感

Comment: @Lucas As noted in the last sentence, it is possible to use 感触 for texture. But it sounds more like personal/subjective sensation.  触感 is more appropriate when referring to texture as property (generally independent from particular feeler).

Comment: @Lucas - To avoid confusion with 食感, I would say 触り心地. 触感 sounds pretty technical, more so than 食感.

Answer (score 0):

触感 means body feeling, while 感触 means mental feeling.